json-server request not found
I can't get index value or URLs but the whole JSON file only.
There is no log.
Can you help me understand what I did wrong or don't know?
Run server
--watch/-w can be omitted, JSON Server 1+ watches for file changes by default
JSON Server started on PORT :3000
Press CTRL-C to stop
Watching db.json...

♡( ◡‿◡ )

Index:
http://localhost:3000/

Static files:
Serving ./public directory if it exists

Endpoints:
http://localhost:3000/actions

Call api
curl http://localhost:3000/actions/btn1_on_url/index
Not Found

curl http://localhost:3000/actions

{
  "actions": {
    "btn1_on_url": [
      {
        "index": 0,
        "urls": [],
        "enabled": false
      }
    ]
  }
}

json server
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server
